# How to get user input from javascript form?

Tags: javascript, html

so my question is pretty simple.

How to I get user input from a form and put it into a variable ?

Im struggling to do this simple task and would appreciate some help.

Here is my code :

html:

```
<body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="input_id" value="">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <div id="alert" style="color: red"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Javascript

```
    var a = document.getElementById('input_id').value;

function wawa() {
    return a;
}
document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "user entered this value: " + " " + a;
```

I would like to do this with vanilla JS and no library.

Thanks.

Comment: Might suggest looking at a basic JS tutorial like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzkAi2QMp7Y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a variable outside your function. All you need is a `button` and an `onclick event`. The `onclick event` calls a function that checks input and writes to the `<div>`.

```js
function wawa() {
  var variable = document.getElementById('input_id').value;
  document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = 'The user input is: ' + variable;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="input_id" value="">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="wawa()" />
    <div id="alert" style="color: red"></div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like this :

```js
var a = document.getElementById('input_id');
a.addEventListener('keyup',function() {
document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "user entered this value: " + " " 
   + this.value;
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input_id" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <div id="alert" style="color: red"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this script if it is work for you:

```
var a = document.getElementById('input_id');
a.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "user entered this value: " + " " 
   + this.value;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple button with a call to a JavaScript function via [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onclick).

The main key your missing is a [JavaScript event](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) tied to your button.

Here is how:

```js
function getData() {
  var a = document.getElementById("input_id").value;
  var message = "user entered this value: " + a;

  document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = a;
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="input_id" value="">
    <div id="alert" style="color: red"></div>
    <button onclick="getData();">Get Data</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

If your form doesn't need to be submitted you do not need a from and could just use a [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/oninput) event to get a more responsive output:

```js
function getData() {
  var a = document.getElementById("input_id").value;
  var message = "user entered this value: " + a;

  document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="input_id" value="" oninput="getData();">
  <div id="alert" style="color: red"></div>
</body>
```

If you want a little tutorial on events this is a good place to start [MDN Building Blocks Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).

Given you need to submit the data you could also try [onsubmit](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp):

```js
function getData() {
  var a = document.getElementById("input_id").value;
  var message = "user entered this value: " + a;

  document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = a;
}

function submittedData() {
  var a = document.getElementById("input_id").value;
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form onsubmit="submittedData();">
    <input type="text" id="input_id" value="" oninput="getData();">
    <div id="alert" style="color: red"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: very extensive answer fjoe. Thank you , but yes my form need to be submitted. datatype needs to be check by browser before being sent to server for processing.

Comment: @coco I have added some content links that should help improve the quality of the answer and give you more to think about and work on :)

Comment: @coco I have added an example for onsubmit that will work with your from to do what you need.